# Why did it take the Cops so long to arrive?

Tags: plot-explanation, home-alone

In "Home Alone", after Kevin calls 911 we go through the spider scene, the treehouse thing, the rope gag, running across the street, through the capture and liberation of Kevin and then after Old Man Marley returned Kevin back home, the cops finally arrived at the Murphys' house. Why did it take those Cops so long to respond? Imagine if it were a real emergency!

Comment: https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=average+response+time+for+911+calls

Comment: It was a real emergency.  If things had gone just a little bit differently Kevin could have been killed.